# django image upload to path is not displaying

Tags: python, django

I have an application where I upload images and the images are uploaded to a specific directory but after uploading which works fine if I attenp to click on the image url I get an error which says
`The current URL, media/gallery/2017/12/28/230-256.png, didn't match any of these` and also the image is not displaying in the browser html
below is my model and view despite having my media path defined in the settings

**Models.py**

```
class Gallery(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=400, db_index=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='gallery/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.image.url
```

**Views.py**

```
def index(request):
    gallery = Gallery.objects.all()
    context = {
        'gallery': gallery,
        }
    template = 'gallery.html'
    return render(request, template, context)
```

**html**

```
{% if gallery.image %}
           <div><a href="{{ gallery.image.url }}" title="{{gallery.name}}"><img src="{{ gallery.image.url }}"></a></div>
           {% endif %}
```

Comment: did you configure properly your settings?

Comment: yes I did configure my settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you are developing, in the project urls.py you must add

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [

] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

This will make your uploaded file accessible by the application.

When on a production server, it is better if the webserver itself (apache, nginx, ..) can reach the location where the files are uploaded, you can find how to configure that in other answers ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17391616/serving-static-files-with-nginx-gunicorn-django) for nginx, and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5682809/django-static-file-hosting-an-apache) for apache

Comment: Thanks. I can’t believe I completely skipped this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML needs to be something like this:

```
{% if gallery.image %}
    <div><a href="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ gallery.image.url }}" title="{{gallery.name}}"><img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ gallery.image.url }}"></a></div>
{% endif %}
```

[`MEDIA_URL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#media-url) should be configured in `settings.py`. This should be set to the base URL from where you're serving the files stored in [`MEDIA_ROOT`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-MEDIA_ROOT).

The URL attribute of the image field stores only the relative URL of the image.

Comment: It’s doesn’t even display nothing with this

Comment: There are a couple possibilities. `MEDIA_URL` and/or `MEDIA_ROOT` are set incorrectly, or you have nothing set up to serve static files.