# My email link doesn't access to the right path

Tags: django, nginx, django-urls

I have a question about my `django settings` and `nginx` in order to display a download link receives in an email generated by a Django view.

**1- Context**

The emailing part works fine. I can receive this one. In this email I created a link which let to download a file stored in `MEDIA` folder.

My issue is about the url generated in the email which works with localhost, but not on my testing environment.

**2- My code in my local environment**

In order to build my download link, I pick up the `protocol` and `domain` through :

```
url = self.request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('home'))
```

Then, in my message, I created a link like this :

```
<a href="{{ url }}{% url '<my app>:export_download' token=token %}">Download link to your export file</a>
```

In local, it gives me :

```
http://localhost:8000//download_export/<my_file>/
```

As you can see, I have a double slashes in my generated url which makes an error.
I solved this issue with :

```
url = request.build_absolute_uri('/').strip("/")
```

The urls.py file looks like this :

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^home$', HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
    ...
    url(r'^download_export/(?P<token>.*)/$', ExportDownloadView.as_view(), name='export_download'),
]
```

**3- My code in my testing environment**

In this environment, I'm using nginx as webserver. The application is available from : `https://subdomain.domain.fr/dev3/<app_name>/home`

The nginx.conf looks like :

```
location /dev3/<app_name> {
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /dev3/<app_name>;
    uwsgi_pass unix://var/run/uwsgi/<app_name>.sock;
```

When I access to the generated download like sent from my testing environment, it gives me an access to :

`https://subdomain.domain.fr/download_export/<my_file>` and not `https://subdomain.domain.fr/dev3/<app_name>/download_export/<my_file>`

It misses something ? How I can add this part `/dev3/<app_name>` ? By default, all other urls access to `https://subdomain.domain.fr/dev3/<app_name>/something` but not my generated link.

Thank you

**EDIT :**

In my uwsgi.ini file, I have this both lines :

```
mount = /dev3/%n=main.wsgi:application
manage-script-name=true
```

So it should work

Answer (score 0):

You should check media_root in settings.py on your staging environment. [Here's a great article](https://timmyomahony.com/blog/static-vs-media-and-root-vs-path-in-django/) on serving media files in Django that might help.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. Because my question is not about MEDIA, but about `nginx subpath`

Comment: You mentioned that the file you're trying to serve is in the MEDIA folder, which is why I linked the article; it deals with how to store and serve MEDIA files (e.g., files that have been uploaded by your user). Midway through, the article also links to this Stack Overflow post on how to deploy static and media files on nginx specifically: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17391616/serving-static-files-with-nginx-gunicorn-django